# WatchKit Issue with Swift dynamic lib

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I am creating a app via phone gap it also has a watch kit extension , suddenly it has started creating an issue on production , it just crashes with message

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib   Referenced
>   from:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3AA8B688-6127-4D4B-B69A-AD2481A62AED/GDRFA.app/PlugIns/GDRFA
>   WatchKit Extension.appex/GDRFA WatchKit Extension

Reason: image not found

I have tried every possible thread on SO.

1. Certificates checked for OU Id.
2. Xcode , phone , system restarted + derived data clear + clean project
3. Embedded content contains swift set to YES in project , set to NO in others .
4. I don't have the library embedded , its a dynamic lib . It works fine when i set containsSwift to YES in watch kit but only works fine in dev and adhoc , while archiving it gives me errors .

Any body facing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines to the target of you're application

```
@executable_path/Frameworks
```

> your_target -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Runpath Search Paths